# Send files through email to EC2 instance owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to send an email from an EC2 instance and join some files with it to the owner of the instance ?

The idea is to compute some things with a Python script, to store the informations in a database and to generate two files of result and log.

It would be great if I can automatize it so that I receive these two files in an email and the instance stops after it.

Comment: A better approach would be to copy the output files to Amazon S3 and then send you a notification via Amazon SNS that the files are available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send email from an ec2 instance using the AWS SES service.

When you launch your instance, you can assign it a role.  That role should have rights to send email using SES, and if you want it to shut down when you're done then you'd add the StopInstances permission as well.

You would then use the AWS CLI tool to stop the instance.  You can get the current instance ID from the instance metadata.